# Make C++ automatically convert int to double

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, ceres-solver

When I have a numeric type, which defines `operator<` for double, but not for int, comparision with int literals does not work. This is a problem, as parts of the standard library, i.e. `std::complex` contain int literals.

Can I make the compiler treat int literals as double when using the type?

Simplified example:

```
// the defined operator
template<typename T>
bool operator<(const Type<T> &lhs, const T &rhs);

complex<Type<T>> complex_number;
1.0 / complex_number; // this fails
```

The failure happens inside the `_Div` method of `std::complex` at

```
template<class _Other> inline
void _Div(const complex<_Other>& _Right)
    // ...
    else if ((_Rightimag < 0 ? -_Rightimag : +_Rightimag)
```

which causes the error:

```
error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Type<T>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
(...)
complex(665): note: while trying to match the argument list '(Type<T>, int)'
      [
          T=double
      ]
```

I think probably the code in `std::complex` should be `_Rightimag < static_cast<_Other>(0)` to work with all numeric types, but I have to work with what the stdlib provides.

As the other type is from a library as well, I am looking for a way to add the implicit conversion to my code.

---

For the actual code: I am using [ceres](http://ceres-solver.org/), which lets you define functors with a templated scalar type for autodifferentiation. The scalar is both evaluated as `T` and as `Jet<T, N>`.

Ceres [defines](https://github.com/kashif/ceres-solver/blob/8ebb0730388045570f22b89fe8672c860cd2ad1b/include/ceres/jet.h#L365) `operator<(const Jet<T, N>&, const T&)`, which allows for `jet < 0.0` but not for `jet < 0`.

In my code I can work around the problem by using doubles or explicitely casting integers to the template type `T`, but when I try to work with `complex<T>` I get into trouble for the methods which compare against integer literals, like the `_Div` method above.

Comment: You say that you define `operator<` for `double` - but in fact you've defined one that takes an arbitrary type `T`. The root of the problem is that there are two parameters that allow the compiler to deduce `T`, and when the two disagree on what `T` should be, you get an ambiguity. There are ways around that (you place one of the `T`s in non-deduced context) - but it doesn't look like you have control over the declaration of `operator<`. So basically, it's poor design on the part of the authors of that library you use.

Comment: I have no control over the library instance methods and I am not sure if I can define a conversion operator outside of the class which is then used by classes like ``std::complex``.

Comment: Ceres should define `<` as a friend ADL operator instead of as a free template operator.  It would fix your problem.  `friend 
bool operator op(const Jet& f, const T& s) { return f.a op s; }` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::complex` template is not required to work with general types. The Standard says [complex.numbers]/2:

> The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double`, or `long double` is unspecified.

If you need to generalize any other numeric-like type to a complex-like type, you should be using some different library or implementing your own.

Comment: This sounds plausible, so I probably need to implement an own complex type with the functions I actually need or use two variables and define functions for the needed operations.

Comment: I wrote an own complex type with the basic operations I need and it works for me. It still feels like something the stdlib should be able to provide, when there is a templated type. On the other hand, ceres needs a lot of explicit casts to its scalar type everywhere, which isn't that nice to work with either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get an implicit conversion by defining a constructor that takes a single parameter (of the type you're converting from).

Comment: Can I define this in my code without patching the library? It is open source, but I would like to link against the unmodified library if it is possible.

Comment: My impression of the question is that all types involved are provided by external libraries and it wouldn't be practical to modify them (such as by adding a constructor).